# Load data in listbox with ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

i have problem in this code, iam trying load evalutionlist elemnts using ajax
i create input dynamic fileds and i want create dynamic list to get data from evalution elemnts into this dynamic list on each time i press add button.

now this part from code to create dynamic listbox and fill it by this function

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/TeacherEvaluation/get_EvaluationElementslist'); ?>"
```

the listbox is criteriA_element_name

```
var criteriA_element_name = document.createElement("select");
                    criteriA_element_name.setAttribute("name", "criteriA_element_name[]" + currentIndex);
                    criteriA_element_name.setAttribute("class"," form-control ");
$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/TeacherEvaluation/get_EvaluationElementslist'); ?>",
            // data:{ "EvaluationElementslist":EvaluationElementslist},
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(result){
                 parsedobj = JSON.parse(result)
                 var appenddata='';
                 
                    $.each(parsedobj.criteriA_element_name, function(index, value) 
                    {
                        appenddata += "<option value = '" + index + "'>" + value.criteriA_element_name + " </option>";    
                    });

                    $(criteriA_element_name).html(appenddata); 
            },
             
        });
```

the data return on google console like this

```
[{"element_ID":"8","sub_criteriA_ID":"7","criteriA_element_name":"\u0639\u0646\u0635\u0631 \u062a\u0642\u064a\u064a\u0645 1","criteriA_degree":"10","weight":"6"},{"element_ID":"9","sub_criteriA_ID":"8","criteriA_element_name":"\u0639\u0646\u0635\u0631 \u062a\u0642\u064a\u064a\u0645 2","criteriA_degree":"10","weight":"4"},{"element_ID":"10","sub_criteriA_ID":"9","criteriA_element_name":"\u0639\u0646\u0635\u0631 \u062a\u0642\u064a\u064a\u0645 3","criteriA_degree":"10","weight":"3"},{"element_ID":"11","sub_criteriA_ID":"8","criteriA_element_name":"\u0639\u0646\u0635\u0631 \u062a\u0642\u064a\u064a\u0645 4","criteriA_degree":"10","weight":"2"},{"element_ID":"12","sub_criteriA_ID":"8","criteriA_element_name":"\u0639\u0646\u0635\u0631 \u062a\u0642\u064a\u064a\u0645 5","criteriA_degree":"10","weight":"4"}]
```

but not showing in the listbox
please review my code and fix it, thanks

Comment: sorry the data return on chrome console

Comment: and i want return criteriA_element_name in the listbox with id

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and here the correct code

```
            //--------------- ajax to load data into dropdownlist --------------------
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/TeacherEvaluation/get_EvaluationElementslist'); ?>",
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(result){
                response = JSON.parse(result)
                 var appenddata='';
                 $.each(response,function(index,data){   
                        $(criteriA_element_name).append('<option value="'+data['element_ID']+'">'+data['criteriA_element_name']+'</option>');
                    });
            },  
        });
        //--------------- ajax to load data into dropdownlist --------------------
```